# jQuery image animation loop

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, loops

Sorry but I am a big rookie with codes, and I am trying to figure out how to loop the clouds move horizontally at random intervals in the sky. 
Here is a link: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/34829763/americasrole/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>What's America's role in our world?</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="background">
        <img class= "cloud" id="cloud1" src="cloud1.png"/>
        <img class= "cloud" id="cloud2" src="cloud1.png"/>
        <img class= "cloud" id="cloud3" src="cloud1.png"/>
        <img class= "cloud" id="cloud4" src="cloud1.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="foreground">
        <img id="fg" src="foreground.png"/>
    </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var delay = 2000;
    var $cloud = $('.cloud');
    var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random()*2000)+9000;
    function runIt() {
        $cloud.animate({
            left: "+1100",
        }, numRand, function() {
            $cloud.removeAttr("style");
            runIt();
        });
    }

    runIt();
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#background{
    background: url("background.png");
    width:1024px;
    height:768px;
}

#foreground{
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    width:1024px;
    height:768px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#fg{
    z-index: 10000;
}

#cloud1{
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top:10px;

}
#cloud2{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top:150px;
    width:170px;
    height:99px;
}
#cloud3{
    position: absolute;
    left: -150px;
    top:250px;
}

#cloud4{
    position: absolute;
    left: 400px;
    top:100px;
    width:170px;
    height:99px;
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want each cloud to animate randomly and separately, then you have to animate each cloud separately rather than doing them all as a group.  As it is, you're starting all the animations again as soon as the first one finishes and keeping them all on the same schedule.

Change to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function runIt(item$) {
        var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random()*2000)+9000;
        item$.animate({left: "+1100"}, numRand, function() {
            item$.css("left", "");   // set back to default
            runIt(item$);            // start again
        });
    }

    // start each cloud separately
    $('.cloud').each(function() {
        runIt($(this));
    });

});
```

Here's a working version that I tweaked the parameters some to make the clouds go off the right edge and then come in from the left edge: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/rZRud/

Comment: Thank you so much! it looks super neat. I am trying to understand the code. When I save the code, the clouds don't move: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/34829763/americasrole/index.html yet it works so perfectly on your jsfiddle

Comment: @Agatha you have an illegal character `Timestamp: 13/11/2012 7:17:04 PM
Error: SyntaxError: illegal character
Source File: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/34829763/americasrole/index.html
Line: 37, Column: 4
Source Code:
});â€‹ ` ... make sure your editor uses UTF-8 without BOM encoding and upload your files in binary mode.